# How to cast a model into its parent?

Tags: django, django-models

I've made a class that, when you save a `User`, creates automatically the `Person` associated with the `User` like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=False, null=False,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def my_post_save_user_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:  # a User = physical -> create the associated person:
        Person.objects.create(user=instance, is_physical=True)
```

Later I've made a `Worker`:

```
class Worker(Person):
    job = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
```

My problem is that I'd like to create a `User` associated with a `Worker` (= not a `Person`).

When I do this:

```
user = User.objects.create(username='test',)
Worker.objects.create(user=user)
```

I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_person_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2230) already exists.
```

This is normal, because `post_save` is triggered when I create the `User`, and then a second time when I create the `Worker`.

You might answer "just remove the auto generation of the `Person`" but I *want* for security reasons to always have a `Person` associated with a `User`. So is there a way to do something like:

```
user = User.objects.create(username='test',)
w = Worker(user.person)
w.job = "the job"
w.save()
```

(I know that *the previous code isn't working*) or is there a way to "cast" a `Person` into a `Worker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
p = Worker(person_ptr=user.person,
           date_creation=datetime.date.today(),
           date_last_modif=datetime.date.today(),
           job=job or _("(not precised)"))
p.__dict__.update(instance.__dict__)
p.save()
```

It works even though it's a bit hackish.